# Website opens in Responsive Mode on Desktop Browser - BootStrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Steps to reproduce issue;

1. Open bootStrap [website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) in chrome with restore session option enable in `chrome->settings->on startup->Continue where you left off`
2. Resize the window to view responsive mode
3. Open the task manager and kill the process (or restart computer)
4. Now open the browser again and let website load completely
   . Now resize browser to full window

Note that a screen like below in screen shot appears; Its duration is very small like a sec or less;

[image]

But on the application I am working built with bootstrap has permanent state like in screen shot until I refresh the Tab. In addition to above steps in my application there is certificate accept too. What would be best work around for this so that each browser accidently closes website should open in full mode rather in responsive view.
**Step5**
[image]
**Step6;**
[image]

Let me know if I am not clear on this. Thanks

Comment: If anything, this is a Chrome bug/feature, maybe report it on the Chrome dev forums instead.

Comment: @DavidG I will report on chrome forum as well; already posted on github but I need to sort out some urgent solution asap.

Comment: In what way is it urgent? I don't really see anything critical here.

Comment: But it's such a contrived method to get it to show up, surely it won't happen regularly enough to worry about.  Tell the client it's a Chrome issue and if they are still angry, you can suggest a different browser.

Comment: IMHO the best workaround for your problem would be to have all your styling done using css, and load the css first--presumably it is a JS problem that is causing this delay in switching between different layouts.

Comment: @ialarmedalien i am already loading the css first, browser load the state in which it was closed, like it was closed in responsive state browser will open the responsive state despite window is resized to full.

Answer (score 0):

Just reload the page on page load this will fix the issue as browser save the window in old state to overcome this issue below is the solution;

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: i hope this gonna work; but page reload involves pretty much cost.